# Roslyn: Determine if ITypeParameterSymbols are equivalent

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to determine with Roslyn if two method signatures are equivalent (ignoring parameter order). It becomes somewhat non-trivial when the methods contain generic parameters.

I would like to detect `AGenericMethod` and `AnotherGenericMethod` below as having equivalent signatures:

```
public void AGenericMethod<X>(X someX, int someInt) where X : IEnumerable<int>
{
    //...
}

public void AnotherGenericMethod<Y>(Y someY, int someInt) where Y : IEnumerable<int>
{
    //...
}
```

It seems like `.Equals()` will return false for the `ITypeParameterSymbols` corresponding to X and Y.

Is there any existing functionality in Roslyn for classing `ITypeParameterSymbols` as 'equivalent' (in the sense of having equivalent constraints)? If not, what would be the best way to implement this (considering that the constraints may themselves be type parameters)?

Comment: You'd need to write a recursive `Equals()` method that, when called on a type parameter, calls itself on every constraint.

Comment: Look at http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Shared/Utilities/SymbolEquivalenceComparer.cs; it _might_ be relevant.  (and it's certainly interesting)

Comment: Another source of gnarliness is self-referential constraints, eg 'where X : IComparable<X>'. I'm starting to feel like you'd need a wrapper class to consider cases like that properly.

Comment: And, worse, `where X : IComparable<Y> where Y : IComparable<X>`. Hmmm...

Comment: Hmm; make your recursive method (which should perhaps be a `SymbolVisitor`) compare type parameters by index only; that should work.

Comment: See also http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Shared/Extensions/ITypeSymbolExtensions.ReplaceTypeParameterBasedOnTypeConstraintVisitor.cs